# Javascript - Change diferent elements of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to apply an operation to several elements in the dom. Those elements are different but the operation is the same for all. The number of those elements in the page can vary each time the page is loaded.

For example:

```
<p>The time is <span class="time">15:50</span>.</p>
<p>The time was <span class="time">10:20</span>.</p>
<p>The time will be <span class="time">23:65</span>.</p>
<p>The time is <span class="time">14:15</span>.</p>
```

Then I want to take each of the time elements and add or remove a fixed number of minutes (the same for all).

How can I do do that?

Comment: use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: use jquery $(".time").html("15:00");

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Sorry Roberson. I've edited my question

Answer (score -1):

Like Macro Man has said, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will help you manipulate the times.

In addition, use jQuery to fetch all the span elements using something like:

```
var timeElements = $(".time");
```

then manipulate each one with moment.js.

Comment: The problem is not how to manipulate the times. The problem is how to get all those elements (that is allready solved by you), change their value and put again in the dom instead of the first one.

Comment: This returns an array, and you can manipulate each elements innerHTML property...

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is by using plain JQuery

```
$('.time').each(function(){

    $(this).html($(this).html() + ' - modified ' + Math.random());

})
```